# Calculate Imageview Frame with Scrollview's contentOffset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to calculate the image frame in my scrollViewDidScroll. When i pull down or up my tableview, i want to change my imageview frames.

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 60) {

    userImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 50 - scrollView.contentOffset.y /6;
    userImageViewWidthConstraint.constant = 50 - scrollView.contentOffset.y /6;

    userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = userImageViewHeightConstraint.constant/2;
}
```

I'm calculating with like that but, i used to a condition for between 0 to 60 content off set. If i use slowly my tableview, it working, but when i pull fast, it is jumping another content off set and it is not entering if condition and my image frames are not changing,i want to change these frames step by step, so what should i do for calculate it?

Sorry for my bad english :). Thanks for your advice and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollViewDidScroll:` is not called for each point change in the offset. It skips some points when scrolled fast.

A crude solution would be to add 2 more conditions:

- `if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <=0)`
- `if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 60)`

Set the constraints to the minimum and maximum value you would expect from your formula.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer, it is working like that, but i curious, is there any way without any condition? Can we use only content off set for calculate these frames?

Comment: You could use a `MAX()` - `MIN()` formula, but why fix something that isn't broken?

Comment: Nope, it is working fine :).  i just curious :) Thanks a lot for your answer and interest.